# How can I blit a pgu gui object in pygame

Tags: user-interface, pygame

I have image.I am trying to load a button on it.The image I'm loading using pygame.image.load function.I'm using pgu gui library with pygame to create a gui.button.Now I have to blit this button on the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will first create a app container "over" the image, and then add the button to this frame, like this:

```
    from pgu import gui 
    my_app = gui.App()
    my_container = gui.Container(width =1200,height = 900)#or whatever width, height you wish
    my_button = gui.Button("Quit")
    app.connect(gui.QUIT,app.quit,None)

    ##The button CLICK event is connected to the app.close method.  

    my_button.connect(gui.CLICK,app.quit,None)
    my_container.add(my_button,100,100)'
```

I hope this helps.